# How to drop non-identity indexes in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, performance, synchronization, replication, infinity

In continuation [PostgreSQL Large Table Logical Replication Infinite Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687976), has the exact same problem

But still could not find information about what non-identity indexes are and how to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all the indexes that do not support a primary key:

```
SELECT i.indexrelid::regclass
FROM pg_index AS i
   JOIN pg_class AS t ON i.indexrelid = t.oid
WHERE NOT t.relnamespace::regnamespace::text
         LIKE ANY ('{pg\_catalog,pg\_toast,information\_schema,pg\_temp%}')
  AND NOT i.indisprimary;
```

Comment: Thank! As far as I understand indentity indexes are primary keys?

The question is - why do we need a replica without indexes, if the master database breaks down, we will not be able to switch to a replica without indexes!

Comment: I have never heard of an identity index. If you use the logical standby as high availability solution (which is strange, since streaming replication is better for that), you would create the indexes once the copy is done. Otherwise, the indexes you create once the copy is done will depend on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not relevant, it was able to solve the basic problem:
[PostgreSQL Large Table Logical Replication Infinite Sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57687976)